# Getting the path of recursively iterated directories relative to the specified entry path

Tags: c++, std, std-filesystem

Consider the example in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) of `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    fs::current_path(fs::temp_directory_path());
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    fs::create_symlink("a", "sandbox/syma");
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

> Possible output:

```
"sandbox/a"
"sandbox/a/b"
"sandbox/file1.txt"
"sandbox/syma"
```

---

I would like to drop from the output the `sandbox/` prefix which was specified when constructing the `recursive_directory_iterator`, eg:

```
"a"
"a/b"
"file1.txt"
"syma"
```

I browsed the documentation but I could not find anything relevant.

It is not a big deal to do a bit of string processing, but I do not like having to introduce a somewhat lower level code, doing a round trip from paths to strings. Is this actually the only shot?

Comment: Could you use `std::filesystem::relative`? Example for inside the for loop: `const auto base_path = fs::current_path().append("sandbox"); const auto relative_path = fs::relative(p.path(), base_path); std::cout << relative_path << '\n';`.

Comment: @Lily `relative` is a great advice. It can be applied in a very straightforward way: 
`std::cout << fs::relative(p.path(), "sandbox") << '\n';` is all I needed. If you make that an answer I would be happy to upvote and accept.

Comment: I have now posted it as an answer and using the shorter syntax you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::filesystem::relative`, this might look like:

```cpp
std::cout << fs::relative(p.path(), "sandbox") << '\n';
```